# Create a new point geometry from origin point geometry, distance and bearing in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

I am trying to create a new point geometry field from this command:

```sql
UPDATE cat.datos_parcelas 
SET    arb_geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_Project(geom, arbdist, radians(arbrumbo)), 32631)::geometry;

-- geom: contains the geometry of the origin point in 32631
-- arbdist: contains the distance from the origin to the new point
-- arbrumbo: contains the bearing.
```

However, I get the following error:

> ERROR:  Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography.
> SQL state: 22023

Any clue how to solve this? Shall I convert first my origin geometry to lat/long?

Comment: If you've got data in UTM, you can use Cartesian math to shift the location. Transforming to geographic, using ST_Project, and transforming back seems like it would be the hard way.

Answer (score 3):

*I was about to add a simple custom function overload to the answer, for `ST_Project` to accept `GEOMETRY` types, but I saw that with PostGIS 3.4 the core function was updated accordingly. So going forward this distinction below will be obsolete!*

---

Two options:

- ***Spherical* translation** of the *Point* via *de-projection into geographical coordinates*:

  ```
  UPDATE
    <table>
  SET
    <geom> = ST_Transform(
               ST_Project(
                 ST_Transform(<geom>, 4326)::GEOGRAPHY,
                 <dist>,
                 <bearing>
               )::GEOMETRY,
               <SRID>
             )
  ;
  ```

  where

  - `<distance>` is given in **meter**
  - `<bearing>` is the *azimuth from true north given in **radians***

- **Cartesian coordinate shift** via basic algebra:

  ```
  UPDATE
    <table>
  SET
    <geom> = ST_SetSRID(
               ST_MakePoint(
                 ST_X(<geom>) + <distance> * SIN(<bearing>),
                 ST_Y(<geom>) + <distance> * COS(<bearing>)
               ),
               <SRID>
             )
  ;
  ```

  where

  - `<distance>` is given in **unit of CRS**
  - `<bearing>` is the *azimuth from true north given in **radians***